# Как создать многомерный массив?

Tags: java, массивы

Никак не могу создать многомерный массив с типом String.
Вот фрагмент массива из Python, который я хочу реализовать в Java:

```
a[0][0] = ["What might an electrician lay?","Tables","Gables","Cables","Stables","Cables"]
a[0][1] = ["By what abbreviation is a compact disc commonly known?","CD","COD","CDIS","COMPD","CD"]
a[0][2] = ["Which colour is used as a term to describe an illegal market in rare goods?","Blue","Red","Black","White","Black"]
a[0][3] = ["Which of these would a film actor like to receive?","Oliver","Oscar","Oliphant","Osbert","Oscar"]
a[0][4] = ["In which country would you expect to be greeted with the word 'bonjour'?","Italy","France","Spain","Wales","France"]
a[0][5] = ["Which word follows 'North' and 'South' to give the names of two continents?","Africa","America","Asia","Australia","America"]
a[0][6] = ["Which country is not an island?","Madagascar","Cuba","Germany","Jamaica","Germany"]
a[0][7] = ["What would you normally do with a beret?","Eat it","Play it","Sit on it","Wear it","Wear it"]
a[0][8] = ["Which of these is a tool for shaping and smoothing wood?","Train","Plane","Car","Bike","Plane"]
a[0][9] = ["What would you expect to see at the London Aquarium?","Flowers","Trees","Steam rollers","Fish","Fish"]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: Обычно берут руководство/учебник по соответствующему языку и читают раздел про массивы.

Comment: Пробовал делать как в учебнике и не получалось. Дальше перекопал с десяток сайтов и нигде не было нормального примера массива, который бы не вызывал ошибки при компиляции.

Comment: Ну, судя по всему, пробовали не как в учебнике...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String [][] array = {{"What might an electrician lay?","Tables","Gables","Cables","Stables","Cables"},
            {"и так далее"}};
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает.

Comment: @Александр не зачто

Answer (score 1):

Используй коллекции(почитай о них).
тут можно использовать список списков(тот же двумерный массив)

```
List<List<String>> stringList = new ArrayList<List<String>>()
```

пример инициализации:

```
stringList.add(new ArrayList<String>(){{add("a"); add("b");}});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, почитаю про коллекции потом.